# checking checkboxList in Yii2 at the time of updating post?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I want to checked Yii2 CheckboxList at time of post update 
my list of options is mention below 
[image]

```
<?= $form->field($category,'title')->checkboxList([1=>'Latest news','2'=>'Unit Performance','3'=>'Latest Technology'])->label(FALSE); ?>
```

I want to check some item at time of update which is selected at the time of post creation `like latest news` .

[image]

Kindly help me

Comment: Refer : http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/53418-checkboxlist-options/

Comment: yes  thanks,but i can't  found appropriate solutions for active form

Comment: Is the value already set from the model? just add the following line of code `$category->title = $array_of_selected_value`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use line of code of example.

```
 $list = [1=>'Latest news','2'=>'Unit Performance','3'=>'Latest Technology'];

<?= $form->field($category,'title')->checkboxList($list)->label(FALSE); ?>
```

If option "Latest news" and "Unit Performance" is selected so, on update selected option value array will be `$checkedList = [1, 2];`

So, Simply assign `$checkedList` array to `$category->title`.
Like as,

```
$category->title = $checkedList;
```

Full example is:

```
 $list = [1=>'Latest news','2'=>'Unit Performance','3'=>'Latest Technology'];

 if(!$category->isNewRecord) {
     $checkedList = [1, 2]; //get selected value from db if value exist
     $category->title = $checkedList;
 }

<?= $form->field($category,'title')->checkboxList($list)->label(FALSE); ?>
```

Comment: nice answer . . .

Comment: $checkedList = [1, 2]; //get selected value from db if value exist 

How can i get these values from databse

Comment: @HimanshuSundariyal you need to store selected value with comma separate or any other string format in DB. when you need to display it than first explode that comma-separated string into an array. and assign that array to model attribute.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code to get array of selected checkboxes.

```
$selected_checkbox_array = Yii::$app->request->post("title");
```

Here if you would like to concat them into string, you can use php's implode function

```
$selected_checkboxes = implode(',', $selected_checkbox_array);
```

Other way is

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()))
{

       $model->title= implode(",", $model->title);

       if($model->save())
       {
              return $this->redirect(['gridpage', 'id' => $model->id]);
       }    
}
```